# SQL Server 2014: Converting a Decimal(18,0) to a Decimal(18,5)

Tags: sql-server, type-conversion

So, due to a mistake made by a previous person working in a particular database, I have a column that should have been a Decimal(18,5), but is instead a Decimal(18,0). (This is, apparently, SQL Server's default if you don't specify the precision and scale.)

I have added a new column that is of the appropriate type, but several attempts at doing a convert, as below, have failed:

```
UPDATE [Case].[TableThatWasBuiltWrong] SET NewDecimalValue = 
CONVERT(DECIMAL(18,5), OldDecimalValue)
```

This returns an arithmetic overflow error - which, while strictly correct, is not something I am concerned with (I have verified that none of the data goes above 5 decimal places at present, let alone the intended limit of 13).

Given this situation, how do I get the contents of OldDecimalValue into NewDecimalValue?

(Edited to correct to the SQL Server version in actual use)

Comment: apparently, there is data over that limit.

Comment: What data type is OldDecimalValue, is it a string type?

Comment: Why not just alter the original column anyway? Regardless, there is something over that limit, most likely the 13 digit part. Run this and check `select max(len(floor(OldDecimalValue))) from TableThatWasBuiltWrong`. Is that result > 13?

Comment: @Chuck op says it's a `decimal(18,0)`

Comment: @scsimon I think `SELECT MAX(OldDecimalValue), MIN(OldDecimalValue)` would be enough

Comment: Try `CONVERT( DECIMAL(23,5) , OldDecimalValue )`

Comment: @M.Ali but...why?, the requirement is to convert it to `decimal(18,5)`

Comment: @Lamak yes if we rely on manual counting of the digits which must have failed the OP already

Comment: @Lamak to accommodate values which already has 18 whole numbers. The requirements is unrealistic.

Comment: @M.Ali I mean, yeah, but that's not what op wants, otherwise there would be no issue

Comment: There's no SQL Server **2015** - we have SQL Server 2000, 2005, 2008, 2008 R2, 2012, 2014, 2016 and 2017 is in the works - which one are you referring to??

Comment: You have a number that is larger than 13 digits before the decimal point. See this [decimal and numeric](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/decimal-and-numeric-transact-sql)

Comment: To identify the offending record(s), try  Select * From  YourTable Where Try_Convert(DECIMAL(18,5), OldDecimalValue) is null

Comment: This will result in some data loss, but will convert it: `convert(DECIMAL(18,5),left(cast(@OldDecimalValue as varchar(18)),13))`

Comment: OldDecimalValue is a Decimal(18,0) - 18 places before the decimal point, 0 after. Chuck's solution worked, by the by.

I meant SQL Server 2014 and apologize for the error.

Comment: @ErikOttosen i would not use that solution since it you will lose data... that's almost always the worst idea but it's your data. If you don't care about losing it, that's on you. I've just never, in my life, heard that someone would find that acceptable.

Comment: I manually validated against the data in question that no data loss occurred after running it - the convert would lose digits that, in my data set, were not in use anyways.

Answer (score 0):

There should be nothing wrong if your values are less than or equal to **9999999999999.49999**

See example:

```
DECLARE @val DECIMAL(18,0)=9999999999999.49999
SELECT @val dec1,CAST(@val AS DECIMAL(18,5)) dec2
```

Will result

[image]

But crossing this limit, even staying within 18,5 range, will cause an error.

Following is within limit but, will through an exception:

```
DECLARE @val DECIMAL(18,0)=9999999999999.59999
SELECT @val dec1,CAST(@val AS DECIMAL(18,5)) dec2
```

will through:

[image]

Comment: And this is because when converting, SQL server is trying to round it?

Comment: yeah, but that's because by doing `DECIMAL(18,0)=9999999999999.59999`, you are implicitly rounding it to `10000000000000`

Comment: Agreed. But I believe he wants to convert data from 18,0 to 18,5. right?

Comment: The intent is from 18,0 to 18,5, yes. It is possible I have the wrong SQL listed above as a result?

Comment: @ErikOttosen it's not ideal but can be used of course.